# WinHttp.WinHttpRequest: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response

Tags: http, lotus-domino, lotusscript

In Lotus a lotusscript agent is using this piece of code from a ScriptLibrary:

```
Set objDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set objXmlHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Call objXmlHttp.SetTimeouts("240000", "240000", "240000", "240000")
objXmlHttp.Option(9) = 2048 
objXmlHttp.Option(6) = True
 objDom.async = False
objDom.LoadXml XmlBody
objXmlHttp.open "POST", Url, False
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(XmlBody)
Status = objXmlHttp.status
responseText = objXmlHttp.responseText
```

The code is sending a POST. POST is from HTTPS to HTTPS URL.
When executing this post in the beginning I sometimes received a timeout, so in turn I upped the Timeouts until I am not receiving any timeouts anymore. But now I am sometimes receiving this error:
*WinHttp.WinHttpRequest: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response*

When I resend the POST request then it works again. Is there any way to stop this errors?
Before the winHTTP type I always used the MSXML2.XMLHTTP object, but because TLS <1.2 will be depreceted for us, I switched to the winHTTP but this sometimes gives problems.

Comment: Not necessarily a solution, but if you have Notes R10 or newer, you can use the native method  NotesHTTPRequest, see https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_POST_METHOD.html

Comment: Or https://www.eknori.de/2019-01-08/noteshttprequest-lotusscript-example/

Comment: Have you tried using PostMan to see what the server is actually returning, and how long it takes? You can send the same request multiple times there, until you get the same error.